# How to crack a password I partially know (I forgot my keepass2 password, oops) with John The Ripper?

Tags: passwords, ubuntu-16.04

How do I do this? I found a way to use keepass2john to get the .kdbx file ready. Is there a way to do this for the key as well, and do I have to use the key if I have one (keepass lets you make a .key file)?

Besides that, yeah I'd like to know if you can apply a "mask-force attack" where it's a brute-force attack, but while knowing part of the password in question. My OS is Ubuntu (GNOME) 16.04.

Comment: from what I'm seeing here, keepass2john cannot work with key files http://www.cervezhack.fr/2013/02/12/bruteforce-a-keepass-file/?lang=en

Comment: Strange, Johnny (a GUI frontend for John The Ripper) supports it. Do I need to crack the key too, or just the .kdbx file?